# Async execution of commands in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, scalability, popen

Requirement - I want to execute a command that uses ls, grep, head etc using pipes (|). I am searching for some pattern and extracting some info which is part of the query my http server supports.

The final output should not be too big so m assuming stdout should be good to use (I read about deadlock issues somewhere)
Currently, I use popen from subprocess module but I have my doubts over it.

- how many simultaneous popen calls can be fired.
- does the result immediately come in stdout? (for now it looks the case but how to ensure it if the commands take long time)
- how to ensure that everything is async - keeping close to single thread model?

I am new to Python and links to videos/articles are also appreciated. Any other way than popen is also fine.

Comment: This is somewhat of an anti-pattern. If you just want to run a pileline, why not use a shell-script? Why do you even need Python? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The number of simultaneous "popen calls" will depend on OS limits and hardware resources.

Comment: @RolandSmith it is part of query processing of a http server.

Comment: one of the reason I posted the question is that I wanted to be as close single thread philosophy.. if needed thread-pools are fine but at the lowest level.. but may be there might be libraries that are not blocking and i could use them..

Comment: What is your specific issue? An async. framework such as gevent, twisted, tornado, asyncio provide means to read subprocess' output asynchronously. Do you need a task queue such as [`celery`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/celery)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `os.listdir` or `os.walk` instead of `ls`, and the `re` module instead of `grep`.

Wrap everything up in a function, and use e.g. the `map` method from a `multiprocessing.Pool` object to run several of those in parallel. This is a pattern that works very well.

In Python3 you can also use `Executors` from `concurrent.futures` in a similar way.

Comment: can IOloop be used and executors be avoided?

Comment: You mean from Tornado? I guess so, if you'd use `Popen` objects directly.

Comment: yes m using tornado. i meant schedule callbacks on ioLoop instead of executor(s).. will take be efficient? I couldnt get Popen related point..

Comment: ioLoop is tied to file descriptors, isn't it? Not sure it would even work with a `future`.